# How to pass ampersand in json body in wso2 esb

Tags: json, rest, wso2, ampersand, wso2-esb

I have an issue when passing **ampersand** inside a JSON body value when calling a REST API on `WSO2 esb`, it gives an exception. But I need to pass this '&' value to the backend via esb and not as `&amp;`.

I tried to send via the following ways, but didn't get any success.

- `&amp;`
- url encoded value
- hexadecimal value

Please help me to solve this issue.

This is the exception which I got.

```
[2016-08-10 13:52:26,538] ERROR -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 3): ' ' (<Unknown Source>#1) in <Unknown Source> at line number 1
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:291)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:235)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:341)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:385)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 3): ' ' (<Unknown Source>#1)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3350)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3340)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3356)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.xml.impl.xmlbeans.XML.createFromJS(XML.java:388)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.xml.impl.xmlbeans.XML.jsConstructor(XML.java:3065)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.xml.impl.xmlbeans.XMLObjectImpl.execIdCall(XMLObjectImpl.java:549)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.construct(BaseFunction.java:313)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2132)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92._c0(<Unknown Source>:1)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92.exec(<Unknown Source>)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
        ... 21 more
[2016-08-10 13:52:26,540]  WARN -  Executing fault handler due to exception encountered {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver}
[2016-08-10 13:52:26,540]  WARN -  ERROR_CODE : 0 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
[2016-08-10 13:52:26,541]  WARN -  ERROR_MESSAGE : The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
[2016-08-10 13:52:26,541]  WARN -  ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator.handleException(AbstractMediator.java:313)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:241)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:341)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:385)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 3): ' ' (<Unknown Source>#1) in <Unknown Source> at line number 1
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:291)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:235)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 3): ' ' (<Unknown Source>#1)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3350)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3340)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3356)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.xml.impl.xmlbeans.XML.createFromJS(XML.java:388)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.xml.impl.xmlbeans.XML.jsConstructor(XML.java:3065)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.xml.impl.xmlbeans.XMLObjectImpl.execIdCall(XMLObjectImpl.java:549)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.construct(BaseFunction.java:313)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2132)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92._c0(<Unknown Source>:1)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c92.exec(<Unknown Source>)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
        ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried same thing with wire logs enabled and it worked for me without any changes. What is the ESB version you tried. If you enabled wire logs you will what comes and what goes out as follows. I added & symbol to body parameter.

```
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "POST /pizzashack/1.0.0/order HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "Host: 172.17.0.1:8243[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,643] DEBUG - wire >> "Authorization: Bearer 0227aad0-bc8c-3a4a-b010-fadb7582b488[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "Referer: https://127.0.0.1:9443/store/apis/info?name=PizzaShackAPI&version=1.0.0&provider=admin[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 169[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "origin: https://127.0.0.1:9443[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "{[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "  "customerName": "string&test",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "  "delivered": true,[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "  "address": "string",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "  "pizzaType": "string",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "  "creditCardNumber": "string",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "  "quantity": 0,[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "  "orderId": 0[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,644] DEBUG - wire >> "}"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "POST /am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api/order HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "origin: https://127.0.0.1:9443[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Referer: https://127.0.0.1:9443/store/apis/info?name=PizzaShackAPI&version=1.0.0&provider=admin[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Host: localhost:9443[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "a9[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "{[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "  "customerName": "string&test",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "  "delivered": true,[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "  "address": "string",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "  "pizzaType": "string",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "  "creditCardNumber": "string",[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "  "quantity": 0,[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "  "orderId": 0[\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "}[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,647] DEBUG - wire << "0[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 11:11:05,648] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: I use 4.8.1 version

Comment: I add the exception which I got by editing the question. Pls refer it. I want to pass value like this "test & test"

Answer (score 1):

I tried same in ESB 4.8.1 as well. Since i saw java script errors in your error log i added java script mediator as well. Please see sample API below.

```
   <api name="TestAPI" context="/test">
      <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/status" faultSequence="fault">
         <inSequence>
            <script language="js">var symbol = mc.getPayloadXML()..*::password.toString();
               mc.setPayloadXML(
                  &lt;m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples/xsd"&gt;
                     &lt;m:request&gt;
                        &lt;m:symbol&gt;{symbol}&lt;/m:symbol&gt;
                     &lt;/m:request&gt;
                  &lt;/m:getQuote&gt;);</script>
            <send>
               <endpoint name="test-I_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                  <http uri-template="http://127.0.0.1:8888/"/>
               </endpoint>
            </send>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
      </resource>
   </api>
```

Then i send request as follows.

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz & abc"}' http://127.0.0.1:8280/test/status
```

I can see my values pass to back end properly. Just to verify i added TCPMon between ESB and back end to verify out going message. Its going back with & sign. Wire logs are here and TCPMon output also attached.

```
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,236] DEBUG - wire >> "POST /test/status HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,236] DEBUG - wire >> "Host: 127.0.0.1:8280[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,236] DEBUG - wire >> "User-Agent: curl/7.43.0[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,236] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,236] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,236] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 41[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,237] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,237] DEBUG - wire >> "{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz & abc"}"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,245] DEBUG - wire << "POST /status HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,245] DEBUG - wire << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,246] DEBUG - wire << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,246] DEBUG - wire << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,246] DEBUG - wire << "Host: 127.0.0.1:8888[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,246] DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,246] DEBUG - wire << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,246] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,246] DEBUG - wire << "2f[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,247] DEBUG - wire << "{"getQuote":{"request":{"symbol":"xyz & abc"}}}[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,247] DEBUG - wire << "0[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-10 14:30:21,247] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
```

[image]